# Handle Push Notification before it is displayed in the Notifications Banner

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I would like to execute some code in the app when it receives a remote notification, before the IOS Notification's Banner/Alert is displayed. The idea is to catch the json that comes in the notification, and based on it's content and other rules I would know if should I display or not the Notification for the user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create "silent" push notifications. (See Apple documentation) When you receive such a silent notification:

- parse the JSON
- decide if you want to show it or not
- if yes, just show a normal local notification, it looks same as a push-notification for the user

You will find plenty of SO tutorials on how to create local notifications.

You have to implement application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: fetchCompletionHandler.

> Use this method to process incoming remote notifications for your app. Unlike the application:didReceiveRemoteNotification: method, which is called only when your app is running in the foreground, the system calls this method when your app is running in the foreground or background. In addition, if you enabled the remote notifications background mode, the system launches your app (or wakes it from the suspended state) and puts it in the background state when a remote notification arrives. However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app automatically again.

Comment: Great thanks!, This is what I was looking for, Nevertheless I was looking around how to make this work also when the application was killed with no result. Any idea?